# Error handling when Exception / Error is thrown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, custom-errors, airbrake

I'll try to keep it short a sweet.

In ruby, what would be the best way to return another value if an exception is thrown? I have airbrake to notify me of the exception for me, but I do not want to stop the process from continuing. So far I have something like this:

```
house = House.find(1)
visitor_count = begin
                    house.visitors.count
                rescue => e
                    Airbrake.notify(e)
                    0
                end
```

Wondering if there is anyway to do this other than a begin block. Thanks!

Comment: begin / rescue is the basic error handling mechanism. it seems like your code is working.

Comment: it is working, but I was wondering if there were other methods of doing the same thing.

Comment: Note that this rescues *all* exceptions that extend from `StandardError`. I hope you did this only for the sake of a simple example. You should *never* blindly rescue such general exceptions, only the ones that you actually *expect* to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution (in isolation) is fine. Here's another way of organizing the same logic:

```
def num_house_visitors(id)
  House.find(id).visitors.count
rescue => e
  Airbrake.notify(e)
  0
end
```

I would recommend that you try to handle or prevent exception cases from happening in the first place, though:

```
house = House.find_by(id: id) # assuming Rails/ActiveRecord
house = Struct.new('MissingHouse', :visitors).new([]) if house.nil? # prevent nil errors

# House#visitors (and MissingHouse#visitors) always returns an array
vistor_count = house.visitors.count # this can't fail
```